# Kendo UI - Draw a circle inside Gauge instead of Slidebar

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik

Hi I am looking into the demo where the Gauge is with a slide Bar inside it.

Here is a demo from Telerik site.
http://dojo.telerik.com/oDoqE

How can I have a circle filled with a specific colour instead of that slidebar? 
Is that something achievable?

Comment: What is a 'slidebar'?

Comment: It is a kendoSlider. If you slide through that, gauge updates. But instead of that I need it to be just a circle.

Comment: OK. Just for reference, there's no slider when you view that link in chrome.

Comment: Sorry Paul.. Now its showing.. I was playing with it earlier.

Comment: What do you mean by a circle filled with a color?

Comment: Now I have an example Gauge to show you all.. http://dojo.telerik.com/oDoqE/2 look at this link now..

Comment: How is a circle filled with a color functionally supposed to replace a slider? The slider is a user input control. They would drag it side to side to pick a number. Are you trying to make a circle that when you click on it sets a number? It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve.